# OpenCV - Turn Transparent Part of PNG white

Tags: python, image, opencv, png

I am new to OpenCV so please bear with me if my qustion seems silly to you.

I have a set of images that all have a transparent border on the left and right like you can see below:
[image]

I want to erase these borders so I thought about edge detection which would be easy to do if I could transform these transparent borders to a white color. In the Docs I found that you can do this:

```
img = cv2.imread("./Green/image-000.png", 1)
cv2.imwrite('../image-000.png', img)
```

This erases the alpha channel of the png image but turns it into black.
Is there something similar that turns the borders white?
Or is there even a simpler method of erasing these borders?
You would make me really happy if you could help me!

PS: I use Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.4

Comment: Why *"erase"* them to black or white? Why not crop them off altogether if not needed?

Comment: The border size differ from picture to picture so I can not enter a certain value for cropping. Maybe I am thinking too complicated though

Comment: You said they are transparent - so you know where they are - they are where the image is transparent.

Comment: I don't know where the image is transparent. How do I find that out?

Comment: Print the top row of pixels out. They are arranged in BGRA order, so the transparency of the first pixel will be the 4th value, the transparency of the second pixel will be the 8th value. You will see a step-change where the pixels cease being transparent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should load image with `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`, i.e.

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread("./Green/imgage-000.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Then, your image will have 4 channels (`BGRA`), and you can use alpha channel mask to turn the corresponding part to white:

```
alpha_channel = img[:, :, 3]
_, mask = cv.threshold(alpha_channel, 254, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)  # binarize mask
color = img[:, :, :3]
new_img = cv.bitwise_not(cv.bitwise_not(color, mask=mask))
```

I tested this code with a transparent PNG where the color channels were black and the information was in the transparency:

[image: input image with gradual transparency]
[image: output image with binary pixels]

The nested `bitwise_not` is ugly but is the only way I found to make it work.