# Need to do transparent black other white

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have image (png) with a transparent background. I need to do all things on image white and all transparent black. I find such solution, it do transparent - black, but other things are gray.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def remove_transparency(source, background_color):
    source_img = cv2.cvtColor(source[:,:,:3], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    source_mask = source[:,:,3]  * (1 / 255.0)

    background_mask = 1.0 - source_mask

    bg_part = (background_color * (1 / 255.0)) * (background_mask)
    source_part = (source_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (source_mask)

    return np.uint8(cv2.addWeighted(bg_part, 255.0, source_part, 255.0, 0.0))



img = cv2.imread('my_image_resized.png', -1)
result = remove_transparency(img, 0)
cv2.imshow('', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Can somebody help me? I am new in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV - Turn Transparent Part of PNG white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816703/opencv-turn-transparent-part-of-png-white)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first read the [unchanged image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547458/4782513) to load the alpha channel.

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("image.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Then you [may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816703/opencv-turn-transparent-part-of-png-white):

```
alpha_channel = img[:,:,3]
mask = (alpha_channel != 0)
color = img[:,:,:2]
new_img = cv2.bitwise_not(color, color, mask=mask)
```